# Dependency injection for FormElement #process callback

Tags: 8, forms

Is there any way to inject container services into FormElement callbacks like '#process'? Or do I need to call \Drupal::container()->get(..)?

I noticed https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form, but this is for forms, not for form element types.

Comment: All form element callbacks are simple callables so you would have to pass the whole instantiated object instead of just a class and method to call...and somehow instantiate it(maybe via wrapper?). In the end, it does not make any sense.

Comment: To clarify: I am not so interested whether it is technically called dependency injection, but if there is any clean way to use container services in a #process callback. It seems the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency injection for any method of a class is done for the whole class. So if you have a dependency for the method you're adding for any method in the class, you will set that as a dependency for the whole class, not just a single function. However, #process callbacks are static functions, and static functions cannot use dependency injection. They should use the `\Drupal::service()` method, which is for static functions and procedural code.

Comment: see comment from @IvanJaros, the class is not instantiated and the callable is a static function, so you have no access to `$this`.

Comment: If the callable is a static function, then there is no dependency injection. Dependency injection is only for non-static methods.

Comment: the downvote was not from me, the answer is not wrong. If you add the comment to the answer, it is clearer, that you mean, no, you can't use dependency injection for the static #process callback.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's possible with the help of [ContainerFactoryPluginInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Plugin%21ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php/interface/ContainerFactoryPluginInterface/8.2.x). The `#process` is just an array of callables, and it's initialized in [getInfo()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21ElementInterface.php/function/ElementInterface%3A%3AgetInfo/8.2.x) which is non-static. So, you have access to FormElement's `$this` when creating the array of `#process` callbacks. Documentation doesn't seem to put any restrictions on `#process` array, except requiring it to be an array of callables (nothing is said about them to be static). Also, it's not enforced by any interface nor class inherited by FormElement. So, generally, the following is possible:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Element;

use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * @FormElement("my_element")
 */
class MyElement extends FormElement implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {
    /**
     * @var MyDependency
     */
    protected $myDependency;

    public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition): static {
        return new static(
            $configuration,
            $plugin_id,
            $plugin_definition,
            $container->get('my_dependency')
        );
    }

    public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, MyDependency $my_dependency) {
        parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
        $this->myDependency = $my_dependency;
    }

    public function getInfo() {
        return [
            '#process' => [[$this, 'processMyElement']],
        ];
    }

    public function processMyElement(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$form) {
        // $this->myDependency available here...
        return $element;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I haven't found any instance of non-static `#process` method in Drupal's core, so maybe there is a convention, or silent agreement, to not use instance methods as callbacks.

Comment: The process element function will be called statically if referenced from outside the class, and will thrown an error. So to make code more bulletrpoof, #process callbacks should be created/treated as static even when in a class like this.

Comment: Well, I don't believe anyone developed a code which enforces static invocation of ready to use (static or non-static) callables provided via ``#process`` array. No matter, from inside or outside of the class. It's kinda useless. :)

Comment: There is a risk that this stuff could be serialized, although I think it can be avoided depending how it is used.